# Excel, macro move one row down and then delete the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to clean up duplicate rows. My data is in a table with filters applied. I have tried using the Excel feature to remove duplicates, but get the following error.

> Cannot complete operation. You are attempting to change a portion of a
>   table row or column in a way that is not allowed. This may occur when
>   attempting to re-arrange cells within a table that affect other table
>   cells in an unexpected way.

So I have created a macro I can manually select a row, then my macro will delete that row. What I want is the macro to move one row down, delete that row and then do it again. How do I get it to do that?

Here's what I have.

```
Sub DeletRow()
'
' DeletRow Macro

    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub

Sub moveselection()


End Sub
```

Comment: Excel has a command to remove duplicates. It's on the Data ribbon. Why not use that instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: because I get an error, I'm assuming because I am using a table.

Comment: Error:
Cannot complete operation. You are attempting to change a portion of a table row or column in a way that is not allowed. This may occur when attempting to re-arrange cells within a table that affect other table cells in an unexpected way.

Comment: In a table you can only delete whole rows, not parts of rows. Please step back and explain the bigger picture. Edit your post. Don't use the comments.